# If $X^{(n)},X$ are càdlàg and $X^{(n)}\to X$ in distribution, do the corresponding transition semigroups strongly converge?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, operator-theory, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

Let

- $\left(\kappa^{(n)}_t\right)_{t\ge0}$ and $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ be Markov semigroups on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ for $n\in\mathbb N$
- $(T_n(t))_{t\ge0}$ and $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ be strongly continuous contraction semigroups on $C_0(\mathbb R)$ (continuous functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ vanishing at infinity equipped with the supremum norm) with $$T_n(t)f=\int\kappa^{(n)}_t(\;\cdot\;,{\rm d}y)f(y)\tag1$$ and $$T(t)f=\int\kappa_t(\;\cdot\;,{\rm d}y)f(y)\tag2$$ for all $f\in C_0(\mathbb R)$ and $t\ge0$
- $X^{(n)}$ and $X$ be real-valued càdlàg Markov processes with transition semigroups $\left(\kappa^{(n)}_t\right)_{t\ge0}$ and $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$, respectively, for $n\in\mathbb N$

> Assume $$X^{(n)}_0\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}X_0\tag3$$ in distribution and $$X^{(n)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}X\tag4$$ in distribution (with respect to the Skorohod topology). Are we able to conclude $$\left\|T_n(t)f-T(t)f\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag5$$ for all $f\in C_0(\mathbb R)$ and $t\ge0$?

The desired claim is part of the following theorem in the book of Kallenberg, but I don't understand his proof:

[image: theorem]
Relevant part of the proof:
[image: proof]

**EDIT**: What's bothering me most: Why are we allowed to assume $X_0=x$ and $X^n_0=x_n$? Can the general case somehow be reduced to that case?

> I don't know how he's arguing that $X$ is almost surely continuous at $t$. Is this really true? In any case, if we assume that $X$ is almost surely continuous, it is at least clear to me that $(T_n(t)f)(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}(T(t)f)(x)$ for all $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb R$ and $x\in\mathbb R$ with $x_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}x$ and $t\ge0$. But why is that sufficient for $(5)$?

Comment: You do not have that $X_t^{(n)} \to X_t$ as $n \to \infty$ in distribution. Note that the functional $$ \pi_t : D(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x(t)$$ is only guaranteed to be continuous at points $x_0 \in D(\mathbb{R})$ for which $t$ is a continuity point.

Comment: @user159517 Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: I figured out the mistake: in my example, the value of $X^{(n)}$ at $t = 0$ was not equal to $X_0$. Lol! Sorry for that, time to go to sleep.

Comment: @user159517 Do you've got an idea how to prove the claim? I don't really understand Kallenberg's argument. (And he's assuming compactness, which I don't want to assume.)

Comment: I agree that the proof seems a little cryptic. Are you specifically interested in the case $S = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @user159517 I've updated the question. It's clear to me now why we've got what he's claiming to be sufficient, but I don't see why it is sufficient.

Comment: @user159517 Do you know why we are allowed to assume that $X_0=x$ and $X^n_0=x_n$?

Answer (score 1):

You know that $T_n(t)f(x_n) \to T(t)f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$ whenever $x_n \to x$ since this is precisely what is given by the convergence in distribution of $X_t^n \to X_t$ for $X_0 = x, X_0^n = x_n$.

In my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3185278/256128) to your other question, I proved the following result:

> **Lemma:** If $E$ is a compact metric space (a locally compact and separable metric space) and $g_n,g$ are continuous functions (that vanish at infinity) on $E$ such that whenever $x_n \to x$ in $E$, $|g_n(x_n) - g(x)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ then $\|g_n - g\|_\infty \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

The proof is somewhat tedious so I won't repost it here but you can find it in my linked answer. Since you have reduced to the case where $S$ is compact,  the lemma implies that $\|T_n(t)f - T(t)f\|_\infty \to 0$ as desired by taking $g_n = T_n(t)f, g = T(t)f$ for arbitrary fixed $f$ and $t$.

Comment: But what if the given $X$ and $X^n$ don't satisfy $X_0=x$ and $X^n_0=x_n$? The only connection between $T$ and $X$ (resp. $T^n$ and $X^n$) is $$\operatorname E\left[f(X_t)\mid (X_r)_{r\le s}\right]=(T(t-s)f)(X_s)\;\;\;\text{almost surely}$$ (resp. $\operatorname E\left[f(X^n_t)\mid (X^n_r)_{r\le s}\right]=(T_n(t-s)f)(X^n_s)$ almost surely) for all $f\in C_0(E)$ and $t\ge s\ge0$. So, if we change the initial distribution of $X$ (resp. $X^n$) don't we loose this connection?

Comment: This is the same thing which is worrying me in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3234403/47771. (And this is related to: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3235408/47771.)

Comment: I would like to accept your answer, but could you tell me what I'm missing (even it is obvious to you)?

Comment: Well you've assumed that if $X_n^0 \overset{d}{\to} X^0$ then you have $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$ in an appropriate skorohod space. So just take $X_n$ to be the markov process with transition kernel $\kappa^{(n)}$ and initial value $x_n$. The operators $\{T_n(t)\}_{t \geq 0}$ are determined entirely by the corresponding transition kernels since $T_n(t)f(x) = \int \kappa^{(n)}(t,x,dy) f(y)$ (in the first edition of kallenberg this is at the bottom of the first page of the chapter on Feller processes and semigroups). This guarantees you are still talking about the right operators.

Comment: From your answer it is still not clear why we've got $X_t^n \to X_t$ in distribution. As noted by [user159517](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/159517/user159517), $$\pi_t:D([0,\infty),E)\to E\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x(t)$$ is only continuous at points $x\in D([0,\infty),E)$ such that $t$ is a continuity point of $x$. And It's not clear to me why Kallenberg is claiming that $X$ is almost surely continuous.

Comment: If this issue cannot be resolved, I think we need to prove the claim about the resolvent analogue to the Trotter-Kato theorem. That's actually easy, but I don't know why the reduction to the compact case is allowed.

Comment: Instead of assuming the author is wrong you should assume that you have missed something and read more carefully. Kallenberg never claims $X$ is almost surely continuous (this needn't be the case - e.g. take $X$ to be a Poisson process). Kallenberg writes "X is a.s. continuous **at $t$**" which really is immediate from the (F$3$) part of Lemma 19.3. Since we want to reason about the fixed time $t$, this is enough.

Comment: Okay, let $t\ge0$. I get that $\operatorname E\left[\rho(X_s,X_t)\right]\xrightarrow{s\to t}0$. But this only yields $\rho(X_s,X_t)\xrightarrow{s\to t}0$ in probability. We would need to show that there is a null set $N$ such that $X(ω)$ is continuous at $t$ for all $ω\in N^c$. But by the aforementioned result we only get that, given $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}⊆[0,\infty)$ with $s_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}t$, there is a null set $N$ such that $\rho\left(X_{s_{n_k}}(ω),X_t(ω)\right)\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}0$ for some increasing $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}⊆\mathbb N$ for all $ω\in N^c$. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, I think we need that $X$ is càdlàg at $t$ (which is the case in the question, but I didn't realize that we need it here). Then, since $X$ has a left limit $X_{t-}$ at $t$, $$\text E[\rho(X_s,X_t)]\xrightarrow{s\to t-}\text E[\rho(X_{t-},X_t)]$$ by the dominated convergence theorem. On the other hand, by the aforementioned result, $\operatorname E[\rho(X_s,X_t)]\xrightarrow{s\to t}0$ and hence (by uniqueness of the real limit) $\text E[\rho(X_{t-},X_t)]=0$. Thus, $\rho(X_{t-},X_t)=0$ a.s. and this yields the claim, since $X$ is right-continuous at $t$. This is what you've meant, right?

Comment: Sorry, I've been too busy to check this but you worked it out without me anyway :) I would say that the conclusion $E[\rho(X_t-,X_t)] = 0$ follows by a one line argument with the triangle inequality (I'm not sure what you mean that it follows "by uniqueness of the real limit") but the idea of the above comment is definitely what I had in mind.