# If $f_n,f\in C_0$ and for all $x_n,x$ with $x_n\to x$ we've got $f_n(x_n)\to f(x)$, then $\left\|f_n-f\right\|_\infty\to0$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $E$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space (if necessary, assume $E$ is a complete locally compact separable metric space) and $$C_0(E):=\left\{f\in C(E):\left\{|f|\ge\varepsilon\right\}\text{ is compact for all }\varepsilon>0\right\}.$$

> How can we show that if $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq C_0(E)$ and $f\in C_0(E)$ with $$\left|f_n(x_n)-f(x)\right|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag1$$ for all $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$ and $x\in E$ with $x_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}x$, then $$\left\|f_n-f\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag2,$$ where $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_\infty$ denotes the supremum norm?

Comment: I believe you want $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, i.e. sequences of real numbers. This clearly isn't true if $y = 0$, or when $f$ is constant. Are there any additional conditions?

Comment: @mechanodroid The question didn't make sense as stated. Sorry for that. What I really want to show boils down to an other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is false. Take $E = \mathbb{R}$ and let $\phi$ be a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) on $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$. Let $f_n(x) = \phi(x - n)$. Then your first condition holds with $f = 0$ since $x_n$ is eventually close to $x$ and the support of $f_n$ is eventually far away from $x$ so for any sequence $x_n \to x$, $f_n(x_n)$ has a zero tail.

However $\|f_n\|_\infty$ is constant.

---

Your result is true if $E$ is a compact metric space. It is clear that $f_n \to f$ pointwise and so the sequence $f_n$ has at most one limit point in the $\sup$-norm. This means that by a standard subsequences argument, it is enough to check relative compactness. The rest of the argument looks long, but essentially just involves checking that your assumption implies the hypotheses of Arzela-Ascoli when $E$ is compact.

First, assume for a contradiction that the sequence $f_n$ is not equicontinuous. Then there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$, there is an $x$, a $y$ and an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x, y) < \delta$ and $$|f_{n}(x) - f_{n}(y)| \ge \varepsilon.$$
I claim we can arrange to have $n \to \infty$ as $\delta \to 0$ (along some sequence) instead of having $n$ be arbitrary.

Set $\delta_0 = 1$. Then there are $n_0, x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $d(x_0,y_0) < \delta_0$ and $|f_{n_0}(x_0) - f_{n_0}(y_0)| \ge \varepsilon$.

Now suppose we have constructed $\delta_j, n_j, x_j$ and $y_j$ for $j < i$ with the properties that $j \mapsto n_j$ is strictly increasing, $\delta_j < \delta_{j-1} \wedge 2^{-j}$, $d(x_j,y_j)<\delta_j$ and $|f_{n_j}(x_j) - f_{n_j}(y_j)| \ge \varepsilon$.

Since finite families of continuous functions on compact sets are easily seen to be equicontinuous, there is a $\delta_i < \delta_{i-1} \wedge 2^{-i}$ such that $d(x,y) < \delta_i$ implies that $|f_j(x) - f_j(y)| < \varepsilon$ for every $j \leq n_{i-1}$. Then since the sequence $(f_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is assumed to be not equicontinuous, there must exist an $n_i > n_{i-1}$ and an $x_i, y_i$ with $d(x_i,y_i) < \delta_i$ such that $|f_{n_i}(x_i) - f_{n_i}(y_i)| \ge \varepsilon$.

Next, by compactness we can assume that there is an $x$ such that $x_i \to x$ and $y_i \to x$ by passing to a subsequence (the limit is the same since $d(x_i,y_i) \to 0$). This is where the argument first breaks without compactness.

All that remains is to bound
\begin{align}
\varepsilon \le |f_{n_i}(x_i) - f_{n_i}(y_i)| \le |f_{n_i}(x_i) - f(x)| + |f(x) - f_{n_i}(y_i)| \to 0
\end{align}
by our assumption, which gives a contradiction. Hence $(f_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is equicontinuous.

We are left to show that the sequence is uniformly bounded in the $\sup$-norm. To do this, by equicontinuity, fix a $\delta$ such that $d(x,y) < \delta$ implies that $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < 1$ for each $n$.

By compactness of $E$, there is a finite set of points $\{x_i\}_{i \le K}$ that form a $\delta$-net for $E$. Then for any $n$ and any $y$, there is an $i \leq K$ such that $d(x_i,y) < \delta$ and so
\begin{align}
|f_n(y)| \leq & |f_n(y) - f_n(x_i)| + |f_n(x_i) - f(x_i)| + |f(x_i)| 
\\ \leq & 1 + \max_{i \leq K}|f_n(x_i) - f(x_i)| +  \max_{i \leq K}|f(x_i)|
\end{align}
uniformly in $y$. Then by our assumption, there is an $N$ such that for each $n \geq N$ and each $i$, $|f_n(x_i) - f(x_i)| < 1$. Putting this altogether implies that 
\begin{align}
{\|f_n\|}_\infty \leq 2 + \max_{i \leq K} |f(x_i)| + \max_{i < N} \|f_i\|_\infty < \infty
\end{align}
uniformly in $n$ so that $(f_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is uniformly bounded. Hence by Arzela-Ascoli it is relatively compact and hence must converge to $f$ in the $\sup$-norm.

---

It follows that your result also holds if $E$ is a locally compact, separable metric space and additionally $|f_n(x_n)| \to 0$ whenever $x_n \to \infty$ (in the sense that for every compact set $C \subset E$, $x_n \not \in C$ eventually). Indeed, in this case it is clear that if we take the Alexandroff compactification $E^* = E \cup \{\infty\}$ of $E$, then each $f_n$ can be identified with $f_n^* \in C(E^*)$ such that $f_n^*(\infty) = 0$, as can $f$. Further $E^*$ is a compact metric space and $E$ can be homeomorphically embedded in $E^*$.

The additional assumption on $f_n$ is exactly what is needed to mean your original assumption holds for $f_n^*$ and $f^*$ and hence by the above result, $\|f_n^* - f^*\|_{\infty,E^*} \to 0$. The result follows by noting that $\|f_n - f\|_{\infty,E} = \|f_n^* - f^*\|_{\infty,E^*}$.

Comment: I guess compactness is the key property. The question arose in the context of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2984589/47771. I don't understand Kallenberg's argument after "We may establish (ii) by showing that ...", unless we can conclude $(2)$ from $(1)$. But he's indeed assuming compactness. Would be great if you know an argument.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I've made an edit that establishes your result if $E$ is a compact metric space and a version of it if $E$ is a locally compact, separable metric space.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your effort! I'll check what you wrote soon.

Comment: Just for the record: If you say equicontinuous, you actually mean uniformly equicontinuous. But clearly, on a compact space, both notions coincide.

Comment: One question regarding your inequality ${\|f_n\|}_\infty \leq 2 + \max_{i \leq K} |f(x_i)| + \max_{i < N} \|f_i\|_\infty < \infty$: Clearly, $$|f_n|<2+\max_{1\le i\le K}|f(x_i)|\;\;\;\text{for all }n\ge N.\tag3$$ But for $n\in\{1,\ldots,N-1\}$, we should have $$|f_n|<1+\max_{1\le n<N}\left\|f_n\right\|_\infty+2\max_{1\le i\le K}|f(x_i)|.\tag4$$ It doesn't matter in the end, but your inequality might fail, if I'm not missing something. Oh, and is there any reason why we don't simply use $\max_{1\le i\le K}|f(x_i)|\le\left\|f\right\|_\infty$?

Comment: We should let $c:=\max_{1\le n<N}\max_{1\le i\le K}|f_n(x_i)-f(x_i)|$ to obtain $$|f_n|<1+c+\left\|f\right\|_\infty\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N.$$ And by the way, isn't pointwise boundedness all we would need to show? And it seems like we didn't use that $f_n$ and $f$ vanish at infinity. So, the claim should be true for all $f_n\in C(E)$ and bounded $f:E\to\mathbb R$ (by the conclusion it then follows $f\in C(E)$).

Comment: I consider the fact that they coincide on compact spaces to be sufficiently trivial at the level of the question that I didn't mention it (especially since the answer is long, Id hoped these details would be filled in by the reader; otherwise the whole thing would be a ridiculous length). As for the inequality, notice that the trivial bound is $|f_n| < \|f_n\|_\infty$ for $n < N$ which is a huge improvement on your inequality $(4)$ and shows my inequality to be valid.

Comment: You do only need pointwise boundedness. I wrote the answer this way because on a compact space with an equicontinuity assumption, pointwise boundedness and uniform boundedness are equivalent. As a result of this, I've seen one or two places formulate Arzela-Ascoli requiring uniform boundedness (of course, this is bad practice) so I decided to just check that since it is no more difficult in my mind. I'm sorry this caused confusion.

Comment: As for the last thing, if $E$ is compact then $C_0(E) = C_b(E)$ (where $C_b(E)$ denotes the bounded, continuous functions) so there is no difference. In the locally compact setting, you at least need to consider functions that converge to some limit at infinity. If you do this then you can modify the result I formulate there and the same proof will work but the statement will get a lot more cumbersome.

Comment: Do you see any chance to prove the following generalization: Given compact metric spaces $E$ and $E_n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$, $\pi_n\in C(E_n,E)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$, $\iota_nf:=f\circ\pi_n$ for $f\in C(E)$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, $f_n\in C(E_n)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ and $f\in C(E)$ with $|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ for all $x_n\in E_n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ and $x\in E$ with $\pi_n(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}x$, are we able to conclude $\left\|f_n-\iota_nf\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$?

Comment: I don't see an obvious way to translate this technique to that case but I don't have much time free to think about it right now so that doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: If you find the time, you can take a look at the separate question I've asked for that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3250867/47771. Maybe we can reduce everything to the setting you've already provided a proof for.