# If $E$ is a locally compact metric space and $f:[0,∞)→E$ is càdlàg, is $f$ càdlàg as a function into the one-point compactification of $E$ too?

Tags: general-topology, compactification, skorohod-space

Let $(E,\tau)$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, $\infty\not\in E$ be an abstract point, $E^\ast:=E\uplus\left\{\infty\right\}$ and $\tau^\ast:=\tau\cup\left\{E\setminus K\cup\left\{\infty\right\}:K\subseteq E\text{ is compact}\right\}$. $(E^\ast,\tau^\ast)$ is a compact Hausdorff space known as the Alexandroff one-point compactification of $(E,\tau)$.

Assume $\tau$ is generated by a metric $d$ on $E$.

> **Question 1**: Are we able to infer that $\tau^\ast$ is generated by a metric $d^\ast$ on E$^\ast$? If so, how are $d$ and $d^\ast$ related? (I've read that $(E^\ast,\tau^\ast)$ is always metrizable when $(E,\tau)$ is separable; even when $\tau$ is not generated by a metric. However, if necessary, assume that $(E,\tau)$ is separable.)
>
> **Question 2**: If $f:[0,\infty)\to E$ is [càdlàg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g#Definition), is $f$ still càdlàg when considered as function into $E^\ast$?

Comment: You should not ask two questions at once, it would be better do ask two separated questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:** The Alexandroff compactification of a metrizable space is metrizable if and only if the original space is separable. Compact metrisable spaces are easily seen to be separable via the following lemma.

> Lemma: If $X$ is a totally bounded metric space then $X$ is separable.
>
> Proof: For each $n$ there is a finite $\frac1n$-net $A_n$ for $X$ (so for all $x \in X, d(x,A_n) < \frac1n$). Then $\bigcup_{n \geq 1} A_n$ is a countable dense subset of $X$.

In particular, if $E^*$ is metrisable, $E$ is homeomorphically embedded in a separable space and hence is separable.

The converse follows from [Urysohn's metrization theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Urysohn+metrization+theorem). It's obvious that $E^*$ is regular Hausdorff since it is compact and Hausdorff. It is a bit more fiddly but not very difficult to show that it is second countable by using the fact that $E$ itself must be second countable since it is a separable metric space.

However the converse obviously fails if $E$ is not metrisable since subspaces of metrisable spaces are metrisable.

**Question 2:** Part of the construction of $E^*$ includes that $E$ is homeomorphically embedded in to $E^*$ via some map $i$. It is then immediate that $f$ is càdlàg as a function valued in $E^*$ since the topological definition of limits is suitably compatible with the definition of the subspace topology.

For example, you want to check that left limits of $f$ exist in $E^*$ and are the same as the limits in $E$.

This means you want to show that for every $t \in (0,\infty)$ and every open neighbourhood $O^*$ of $\lim_{s \uparrow t} f(s)$ in $E^*$ (where the limit is taken in $E$) there is an $\varepsilon >0$ such that $f(s-\varepsilon,s) \subset O^*$. But $O^* \cap E$ is an open neighbourhood of $\lim_{s \uparrow t} f(s)$ in $E$ and so there is an $\varepsilon$ such that $f(s-\varepsilon,s) \subset O^* \cap E$ since is cadlag as an $E$-valued function.

The right-continuity is then similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Could you take a look at my other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3139957/if-f-n-f-in-c-0-and-for-all-x-n-x-with-x-n-to-x-weve-got-f-nx-n-to-fx?

Comment: With "homeomorphically embedded" you mean that $\iota:E\to E^\ast$ is bijective, continuous and $\iota^{-1}$ is continuous too, right? How is $\iota$ defined?

Comment: No. $\iota$ is bijective on to a proper subspace of $E^*$ (missing exactly the point at infinity you added to get $E^*$). $\iota(E)$ with the subspace topology induced by $E^*$ is homeomorphic to $E$ via $\iota$. Exactly what $\iota$ is will depend on the exact construction of $E^*$ but you should think of $E^*$ as being the thing you get by adding a point $\infty$ to $E$ and then declaring a neighbourhood basis of $\infty$. In this case, $\iota$ is the obvious inclusion map.

Comment: Sure. So, if $f:[0,\infty)\to E$ and $$f^\ast:[0,\infty)\to E^\ast\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto f(t),$$ we can simply conclude that if $f$ has a left-limit at $t>0$, $f^\ast=\iota\circ f$ has a left-limit (and the same for right-continuity), simply because $\iota:E\to E^\ast$ is continuous, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: If $f\in C_0(E)$, then $$f^\ast(x):=\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{, if }x\in E\\0&\text{, if }x=\infty\end{cases}\tag1$$ is a continuous function $E^\ast\to\mathbb R$. On the other hand, if $g^\ast\in C(E^\ast)$, then $g:=\left.g\right|_E-g^\ast(\infty)\in C_0(E)$. Is any function in $C(E^\ast)$ the extension (given by $(1)$) of a function from $C_0(E)$?

Comment: If not is $\left\{f^\ast\text{ given by }(1):f\in C_0(E)\right\}$ at least dense (wrt the supremum norm) in $C(E^\ast)$?

Comment: That set is exactly the set of $g^* \in C(E^*)$ such that $g^*(\infty) = 0$. Obviously this isn't dense. This is obvious from your construction since you recognised you had to subtract off the value $g^*(\infty)$ to get a $C_0(E)$ thing.

Comment: I see. Hm, then I don't understand a proof in Ethier and Kurtz. If I remember correctly, you're also familiar with probability theory, right? I'm trying to understand how the authors conclude that $\left\{X_n\right\}$ (i.e. the sequence of distributions) is relatively compact in $D([0,\infty),E^*)$ (càdlàg functions) in the [proof of Corollary 9.3](http://tinyurl.com/y2pof744) (their $\hat C(E)$ is $C_0(E)$ and $E^\Delta$ is $E^*$). I don't even understand why $\left\{f\circ X_n\right\}$ is relatively compact for all $f\in C(E^*)$ (it's only assumed that this is the case for $f\in C_0(E)$)

Comment: Do you've got a reference for the claim "the Alexandroff compactification of a metrizable space is metrizable if and only if the original space is separable"?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't really my area so I don't know a reference sorry.