# Conclude $\left\|f_n-f\right\|_\infty\to0$ from knowing that $f_n(x_n)\to f(x)$ for all $(x_n)$ and $x$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X_n,d_n),(Y,d_Y)$ be compact metric spaces for $n\in\mathbb N$, $\pi_n\in C(X_n,Y)$, $$\iota_nf:=f\circ\pi_n\;\;\;\text{for }f\in C(Y)$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$, $f_n\in C(X_n)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ and $f\in C(Y)$.

> Assume $$|f_n(x_n)-f(y)|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag1$$ for all $x_n\in X_n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ and $y\in Y$ with $\pi_n(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}y$. Are we able to conclude $$\left\|f_n-\iota_nf\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag2?$$

Note that [the result holds if $E_n=E$ and $\pi_n$ is the identity for all $n\in\mathbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3185278/47771).

**EDIT**: Maybe we are able to use the known result from the link. Note that the condition in $(1)$ is equivalent to $$|(f_n-\iota_nf)(x_n)|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag3$$ for all $x_n\in X_n$ such that $(\pi_n(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent.

Note that $$X:=\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n$$ equipped with $$d_X(x,x'):=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}2^{-n}d_n(x_n,x'_n)\;\;\;\text{for }x,x'\in X$$ is a compact metric space. By the result from the link, if $(g_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq C(X)$ and $g\in C(X)$, then $$\left|g_n\left(x^{(n)}\right)-g\left(x^{(n)}\right)\right|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag4$$ for all convergent $\left(x^{(n)}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq X$ (or, equivalently, $$\left|g_n\left(x^{(n)}\right)-g(x)\right|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag5$$ for all $\left(x^{(n)}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq X$ and $x\in X$ with $d_X\left(x^{(n)},x\right)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$), then $$\left\|g_n-g\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag6.$$

Now, let $$g_n(x):=(f_n-\iota_nf)(x_n)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in X$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. We would need to show that if $\left(x^{(n)}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq X$ is convergent, then $$\left|g_n\left(x^{(n)}\right)\right|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag7.$$ In order to do so, we would need to show that $\left(\pi_n\left(x^{(n)}_n\right)\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent and proceed accordingly. Are we able to do so?

Comment: $f_n-f$ is not defined, I think...

Comment: Do you want $\|f_n - \iota_n f\|_{\infty} \to 0$?

Comment: @Mindlack Sorry, intended to write $f_n-\iota_nf$.

Comment: @user159517 Yes, of course. Sorry.

Comment: @0xbadf00d still, something about (1) is odd. We have $f_n (x_n) \in E_n$ and $f(x) \in  E$.

Comment: @user159517 No, we have $f_n(x_n)\in\mathbb R$ and $f(x)\in\mathbb R$. As usual, $C(E)=C(E,\mathbb R)$. (But I need to admit that I'm always confused by that too, since the convention in operator theory is "$(E)=(E,E)$")

Comment: The answer to the question in your edit is no. The problem is that convergence in $X$ is really nothing other than coordinatewise convergence but the sequence $\pi_n(x_n^{(n)})$ also depends on the tail behaviour of the sequences $(x^{(n)}_k)_{k \geq 0}$. For example, take $X = \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ and let $x^{(n)} = x = (1,0,1,0,1,\dots)$ for each $n$. For $\pi_n$ take the identity map. Then $x^{(n)} \to x$ in $X$ trivially but the sequence $(\pi_n(x_n^{(n)}))_{n \geq 0}$ is equal to $(1,0,1,0,1,\dots)$ which does not converge.